# Write pandas DataFrame to HDF in memory buffer

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I want to get a dataframe as hdf in memory.  The code below results in "AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'put'".  I am using python 3.5 and pandas 0.17

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
buf = io.BytesIO()
df.to_hdf(buf, 'some_key')
```

Update:
As UpSampler pointed out "path_or_buf" cannot be an io stream (which I find confusing since buf usually can be an io stream, see [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).  Other than writing to disk and reading it back in, can I get a dataframe as hdf in memory?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to do that?

Comment: I just came to the same point, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your first argument to 
    df.to_hdf()
has to be a "path (string) or HDFStore object" not an io stream. Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that.  to_csv has a similar argument path_or_buf where buf can be an io stream, which is why I got confused.

Comment: CSV is a a bulit-in module and HDF is external. I don't know what pandas is using for HDF file access, could be pytables or pyhdf...

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
df.to_hdf(path_or_buf='path\to\your\file')
```

refer [pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)

Comment: I want it in memory, not on disk, and would prefer not writing to disk and then reading it back in